# Error in importing CSV data into MySQL database using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm importing CSV file into database using PHPMyAdmin. I have kept null for the columns that I don't want to import values right now. When I import CSV it is giving me an error: #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'updated_at' at row 1.

Is there a way to want to get rid of this error without importing values into 'updated_at' column.

Note: 'updated_at' is a date time column. It is created using following query.

```
ALTER TABLE labdata1 ADD updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: can you paste row 1 contents that is giving the error?

Comment: Here is the line:                                       1,10.64.4.81,IB-1000-DNS-01,,,,,,,,0002200712000093,,,,Acquired from training,

Comment: strange, I couldn't reproduce this error. I created a column with the same exact query as yours and was able to import blanks and random text that got converted to 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I will try to find the solution and let you know.